# Custom property editor not working on VS2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I wanted to create a custom property editor for a property of my component. To do this, I created a component and a property editor in the DemoControls project (WinForms control library, .NET 6):

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    [Editor(typeof(CustomKeyEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string CustomKey { get; set; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class CustomKeyEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        //...

        return "12";
    }
}
```

After that I add the DemoControls project to the Demo project reference and add the UserControl1 component to the Form1 as in this image:

[image]

But, the CustomKeyEditor doesn't work in edit mode but works in runtime mode.

[image]

Then I found this example and built:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

But the example is also not working.
[image]

For all projects I used .NET 6.
If I use .NET Framework 4.8 all my codes work correctly:
[image]

**Additional Information:**

```
OS: Windows 11 Pro (21H2)

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.3.5
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.3.5+32922.545
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04161

Installed Version: Community

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.3.376.3011
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.3.376.3011
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   4.3.0-3.22470.13+80a8ce8d5fdb9ceda4101e2acb8e8eb7be4ebcea
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.22179.3
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

NuGet Package Manager   6.3.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Python - Profiling support   17.0.22179.3
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.22179.3
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

TypeScript Tools   17.0.10701.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.3.0-3.22470.13+80a8ce8d5fdb9ceda4101e2acb8e8eb7be4ebcea
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.22363.4+1b94f89d4d1f41f20f9be73c76f4b229d4e49078
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.
```